# Execute ng-repeat once

Tags: html, angularjs

My problem should be quite simple.

If in `vm.application.obligations` object I don't have a holderId == 2, I just want to insert a empty row

But my code is inserting one empty row for each `vm.application.obligations`.

How can I insert only one empty row?

```html
<tr class="text-center" ng-if="obligation.debtor.holderId != 2"
    ng-repeat="obligation in vm.application.obligations track by $index">
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Map your data before sending to view

Answer (score 0):

it would be great idea to move the logic into javascript, and to let html show the data without the need of conditions.
for example.
js:

```
vm.uiData = [];                
obligations.forEach(function (obligation) {
                    if (obligation.debtor.holderId === 2) {
                        vm.uiData.push("");
                    } else {
                        //  push to uiData what should be displayed in the normal behavior..
                }
            });
```

html:

```
<tr class="text-center" ng-repeat="text in vm.uiData track by $index">
  <td>{{text}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If in `vm.application.obligations` object I don't have a `holderId == 2`, I just want to insert a empty row

```
<tr class="text-center" ng-if="vm.noHolderIdEq2()"
    ̶n̶g̶-̶r̶e̶p̶e̶a̶t̶=̶"̶o̶b̶l̶i̶g̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶v̶m̶.̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶o̶b̶l̶i̶g̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶"̶ >
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
</tr>
```

```js
vm.noHolderIdEq2 = function() {
    var arr = vm.application.obligations.filter(x => x.holderId == 2);
    return arr.length == 0;
};
```